# Remove brew completely from my system

Tags: command-line, bash, .profile

I interrupted the execution of `homebrew` while installing. Consequently, I ran into a problem mentioned here [Error found when loading /home/user/.profile:](https://askubuntu.com/q/1323204/1191829). I had to comment `eval` statements in the configuration file to solve the problem. However, I completely want to remove `brew`. Kindly, suggest any solution.

Comment: Knowing how to uninstall a program depends on how you tried to install it.  Thus, what method did you use to try to install it?

Comment: Indeed, provide the instructions you followed, and indicate where you cancelled the installation. Anyway, if you do not have any more visible issues, then the little files that may be left somewhere in your system will, as such, do no harm except from taking up a little space on your drive.

Comment: didn't the [uninstall](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew) instruction work?

Comment: @RonJohn I used https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew to install and interrupted it sometime when it was installing homebrew core (Not sure though).

Comment: @bac0n After I commented the eval stmt, the warning went off. Later, I used the prescribe code(same as your share)  to uninstall. Now, how do I check if there are any reminiscence of it?

Comment: "Now, how do I check if there are any reminiscence of it?" Ask another question!!!  Something like, "How do I verify that a program installed from GitHub was completely uninstalled?"

Comment: @RonJohn Here https://askubuntu.com/q/1323242/1191829

Comment: @Lawhatre I skim through *install.sh* and it looks like line: [428-434](https://github.com/Homebrew/install/blob/dee8df98bfb65588007c666034c6e1ad0733b1b6/install.sh#L428) summarizes what is installed besides $HOME/linuxbrew/ (or /$HOME/.linuxbrew?).

Comment: @bac0n This is probably the best answer. I checked the terminal part of each path mentioned and they don't exist. we done mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to check if it left anything behind in one of the system directories:

https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/Unpkg-View.md

You'll still have to carefully go through your home directory to check if it left anything behind there.

Answer (score 3):

I installed brew with the [homebrew install script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh) which installs in `/home/linuxbrew/`.

I just found that one folder, where it resided, I removed that, and freed up 3GB:

```
sudo rm /home/linuxbrew/ -Rf
```

Check for remaining brew components with

```
locate -e brew | egrep -iv '(hebrew|ansible)' | grep brew
```

Answer (score 0):

From [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57207954/how-to-completely-uninstall-brew-and-re-install-brew-in-ubuntu-19-04) and [documentation](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew):

1. Remove with the provided uninstallation script

   ```sh
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
   ```

   As always, before running any script from internet on your machine, it is a good practice to read the source code to check if it only does what it should.
2. Remove directories for some reason not removed by the uninstaller:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /home/linuxbrew/
   ```
3. Remove also the following line from `~/.profile`:

   ```
    eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
   ```

   Otherwise you will get [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1296219/349837) awful blocking message while trying to login.

Run `sudo du -sh /home/linuxbrew/` to compare the space gain (probably at least 1GB).

Comment: In point 1., when the uninstall script is provided as a standalone and accessible file, I would rather download it from github, review the copy on my local machine to make sure that it does not try to do anything beyond its hoped scope (If I found anything doubtful in it, theoretically I could even ask the author on github for a clarification), and then I would execute that reviewed copy of it.

Comment: @Levente Sure, we should always check. I added a warning in this regard. In this case is the uninstallation script officially from Homebrew project.